# Where do I get a frame for my electric drum kit

Tags: drum-kits, electronic-drumset

I found an old electric drum kit in my friends garage. He had a Simmons SD5x Drum kit. However, somehow he's lost the frame while moving houses. They don't sell that model anymore, any idea where I can get a frame from?

Comment: I'd guess that a frame from Yamaha drums would be the same. Check the diameter of the clamps, and check with Yamaha - or any other electronic kit maker.

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful that the frame has changed much, and I reckon Alesis, Roland , Yamaha etc. will all be the same od.tubing. Haven't a clue where in the world you are, but looking on Ebay, there's lots available.